# Why does a container inside a container loses its background color when floated?

Tags: html, css

My "my-works" container is set to a light gray background-color. Inside this container, there are two  articles and their container are named as "my-blog"  and "my-game"

I floated "my-blog" and "my-game" to left and it loses its background-color.

Why does the background color of the second container ("my-blog" and "my-game") inside "my-works" (the parent container ) does not have the same background color that is set to its parent container?

The html code

```
    <section class="my-works">
        <h3> MY WORKS </h3>

        <article class="my-blog">
            <h4>My Blog</h4>
            <img src="blog.png" width="45%">
        </article>

        <article class="my-game">
            <h4>A Tambay Inspired Flappy Bird - Yotni Bird</h4>
            <img src="flappybird.png" width="45%">
        </article>

    </section>
```

The CSS code

```
    .my-works {
    width:100%;
    background-color: #F0F0F5;
        }

    .my-works h3 {
        text-align:center;
        margin-top: 0;
        padding: 20px;

        }

    .my-blog {
        width: 40%;
        float:left;


        }
    .my-game {
        width: 40%;
        float:left;


        }
```

here's the image

[image]

Comment: On your ".my-works" container, add "overflow: auto;". that should allow the container to respect the floated elements. You can also try "clear: both;" on the container if overflow does not work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `.my-works` div will no longer completely wrap the inner divs, because of the floats applied.

You would need to add some sort of clear or clearfix to the `.my-works` div

**clearfix**

```
.my-works:before,
.my-works:after { 
    content: ""; 
    display: table;
}
.my-works:after {
    clear: both;
}
```

Or you could add a tag with `clear:both;` to your html.

**clear**

```
<section class="my-works">
    <h3> MY WORKS </h3>

    <article class="my-blog">
        <h4>My Blog</h4>
        <img src="blog.png" width="45%">
    </article>

    <article class="my-game">
        <h4>A Tambay Inspired Flappy Bird - Yotni Bird</h4>
        <img src="flappybird.png" width="45%">
    </article>

  <br style="clear:both">

</section>
```